# About differentiability and continuity $A(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, continuity

For some $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ integrable in every interval $[a, b]$ of $\mathbb{R}$, consider $A(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$.

**(i) Is it true that $A$ is differentiable?**

I don't know how to connect the fact that $f$ is integrable with this preposition... is that possible?

**(ii) Is it true that if $f$ is differentiable in some $c$ then $A'$ is continuous in c?**

I was thinking that if $f$ is differentiable in $c$, then $f$ is continuous in $c$. So by the fundamental theorem of calculus $A$ is differentiable in $c$, then continuous. Am I right?

Comment: idk if (i) is true, consider f(t) = 1 for t <= 1 and 2(t-1) for t > 1

Comment: I think that (i) is true from the Leibniz rule. But (ii) is not true from the counter-example provided by cand.

Comment: can you explain me the Leibniz rule?

Comment: Are you assuming Riemann's integral?

Comment: To all the various commenters: If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, must it be continuous on an interval around $c$?

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, you are right. I did not thoroughly check this.

Answer (score 3):

The part i) of the exercise is easy to check that doesn't holds in general, by example taking the function $f(x)=1$ if and only if $x\in[0,1]$ and zero otherwise.

However the part ii) is a bit problematic because $A'$ may not exists in any neighborhood of $c$. Note that $A'$ doesn't exists at a point when $f$ have a non-removable jump discontinuity at this point.

Now let
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}
\frac1{n},&x\in[\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n})\text{ for any }n \in \Bbb N_{> 0} \\
x,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is continuous and differentiable at zero because
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac1{\lfloor \frac1{h} \rfloor h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac1{1-\left\{\frac1h\right\}h}=1
$$
where $\lfloor \cdot  \rfloor$ is the floor function and $\left\{\cdot \right\}$ is the fractional part function. However $A'$ doesn't exists at each $x=1/n$, therefore doesn't exists a neighborhood of zero where $A'$ exists.

Comment: Could you explain me how that $f(x)=\begin{cases}
1, \ x \in [0,1] \\
x, \ { otherwise }
\end{cases}$ is a counter-example?

Comment: because $A'(0)$ and $A'(1)$ doesn't exists

Comment: Great example. +1

Comment: sorry i didn't understand exactly why $A’$ doesn't exist at every point $1/n$. Could you detail more?